# Can I create an alias name for a subquery so I can use the alias in other subqueries?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a lengthy oracle SQL script that uses several subqueries. Is there a way that I can avoid repeating the subquery script if I want to use the same subquery as part of another calculation, e.g. in the following much smaller script, can I give the 'onhand_uk' subquery an alias so I can only use the alias name in the 'running_stock_UK' subquery ?

```
select distinct 
    trunc(al.date_required) date_allocated, 
    al.component_part, al.qty_required, 
    sum(al.qty_required) over (partition by al.component_part order by trunc(al.date_required), al.component_part) running_demand_UK,
    (select sum(pl.qty_onhand) 
     from part_loc pl 
     where al.component_part = pl.part_no and pl.plant in ('W','2') and pl.location_type = 'IN') onhand_UK,
    (select sum(pl.qty_onhand) 
     from part_loc pl 
     where al.component_part = pl.part_no and pl.plant in ('W','2') and pl.location_type = 'IN') - sum(al.qty_required) over (partition by al.component_part order by trunc(al.date_required), 
    al.component_part) running_stock_UK
from 
    allocations al, part_description pd
where 
    al.alloc_plant = 'W'
    and al.status_code between '4' and '8'
    and al.component_part like 'Y%'
    and al.component_part = 'Y450569'
    and al.component_part = pd.part_no
    and substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','KT','TR')  
order by 
    al.component_part, trunc(al.date_required)
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Your google search string is, "oracle with clause"

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Dan Bracuk, I though you were looking for the [`WITH` statement](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_with_clause.htm) as well, but I've taken a look at your query and in this case I would just move everything to a subquery, and pull out the subtraction to the main query:

```
select
  x.date_allocated,
  x.component_part,
  x.qty_required,
  x.running_demand_UK,
  x.onhand_UK,
  x.running_demand_UK - x.onhand_UK as running_stock_UK
from
    (select distinct 

      trunc(al.date_required) date_allocated, 
      al.component_part, al.qty_required, 

      sum(al.qty_required) over (
            partition by al.component_part 
            order by trunc(al.date_required), al.component_part) running_demand_UK,

      (select sum(pl.qty_onhand) from part_loc pl 
       where al.component_part = pl.part_no 
            and pl.plant in ('W','2') 
            and pl.location_type = 'IN') onhand_UK

    from allocations al, part_description pd

    where al.alloc_plant = 'W'
        and al.status_code between '4' and '8'
        and al.component_part like 'Y%'
        and al.component_part = 'Y450569'
        and al.component_part = pd.part_no
        and substr(pd.prodtyp,1,2) in ('JC','KT','TR') ) x
order by 
  x.component_part, 
  x.date_allocated
```

Comment: Brilliant ... that has halved my 200+ line script - much easier to create additional subquery calculations now. THANK YOU !!!